# calendar push notification to java app engine backend servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-calendar-api, backend

I want to get push notification from google calendar into my java app engine backend servlet. My question is, do I need to verify my java app engine backend servlet (which is hosted on google app engine server)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to verify the domain even if it is hosted by Google App Engine. Remember to always use HTTPS otherwise you won't be able to do it. To verify the easiest way is to create a static HTML file that points to the same file name in the root of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it can't and I tried using HTML file and meta tag method without any luck to verify my app engine backend site.